# Annotation vs Grease Pencil

Tags: grease-pencil, annotation

I'm new to Blender (2.9), just getting through the [docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest), and also new to animation.

> An annotation is extra information associated with a particular point in a document or other piece of information. –[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annotation)

It seems like Grease Pencil can do everything that Annotation can, and more, and I'm hoping for some insight as to the role and practical usage of Annotation, as opposed to Grease Pencil.

Comment: since 2.8 annotation has mostly become a way to write some informations, like a post-it, while grease pencil is made to create 2D animations

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main difference is that annotations are meant to be notes, or sketches for reference only. There is no way to render them and cannot be animated.

Grease pencil objects are renderable, and can be animated. They are designed as a "hand drawn" animation tool in a 3D environment.

Answer (score 6):

When you create an Annotation , it is used to be used as a reference , for example you can use to annotate a bad geometry in object mode and then go to wireframe mode fr solving that problem still knowing where it is because to annotated it .On the other side , you can use Grease pencil to make 2d animations in the Blender 2d preset and also to serve the same purpose as annotations , but the annotations doesn't have the features grease pencil like size materials and others.